# What kind of configuration needed to deploy dockerized rails in VPS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

My rails project was working fine until I dockerized it. Below is my configuration. First, `docker-compose build` and then `docker-compose run app rails db:migrate` and finally, `docker-compose up`. I'm deploying in DigitalOcean with pre-installed Docker image **(Ubuntu Docker 5:19.03.1~3 on 18.04)**. I'm not using Nginx, this is only Puma. I have `force-ssl` turned off in `production.rb`. Any help would be appreciated.

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.7.1-buster

ENV RAILS_ROOT /fulfillme

# Add NodeJS to sources list
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -

# Add Yarn to the sources list
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
  && echo 'deb http://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y \
  build-essential \
  nodejs \
  yarn \
  libpq-dev && \
  mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT && \
  apt-get clean autoclean && \
  apt-get autoremove -y && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt /var/lib/dpkg /var/lib/cache /var/lib/log

WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT

ENV RAILS_ENV='production'
ENV SECRET_KEY_BASE='somekey'

COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock

RUN bundle config set without 'development test'
RUN bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5

COPY package.json package.json
COPY yarn.lock yarn.lock

RUN yarn install --check-files

COPY . .

RUN bundle exec rails assets:precompile

# EXPOSE 3000

# CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
volumes:
  postgres-data:
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    # restart: always
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432
      - RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true
    # volumes:
    #   - .:/project # Only mount this volume if running Rails in development mode.
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    # restart: always
```

Below is the output from the server after I run `docker-compose up` and serve the page from http://{ip address}.com .

[image]

Comment: Not sure if the url you added is the one you're trying to connect to, but in case you are, you only need to open `http://{ip address}` without the `.com`

Comment: Are there logs from the Rails process that you can include in your question (as text; never use a screen shot of a terminal window in place of actual logs or source code)?  What's the specific problem you're running into?